# Overlapping fragment with activity view

Tags: android

I am following a fragment example https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/2947119.

I am adding the fragment dynamically after button click event.But the fragment is overlapping with the button. And when I am pressing back key on this screen, activity is closed.

Need help to display only the fragment after button is clicked and if the back is pressed after adding fragment, then only the top fragment should be closed.

Here are my test code.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static Button mBtn;
private static final String TAG_LIST = "list";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
return;
}

mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickme);
mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_LIST);
             if (fragment == null) {
                 fragment = TestListFragment.newInstance();
                 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, TAG_LIST);
                 ft.commit();
             }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

TestListFragment.java

```
public class TestListFragment extends ListFragment {

public static TestListFragment newInstance() {
    return new TestListFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState){
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(android.R.id.content, container, false);        
    return rootView;
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_column, R.id.text);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(createDataList(10));
}

private static List<String> createDataList(int counts) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++) {
        list.add("i=" + i);
    }
    return list;
}

@Override  
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //On item click, launch the DialogFragment
    TestDialogFragment moveFragment = new TestDialogFragment( );
    moveFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Test List Fragment");
}
```

TestDilogFragment.java

```
public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private View testDialogFragment = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Fill the layout as per Your requirement
    testDialogFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_fragment, container);
    return testDialogFragment;
}

 }
```

activity-main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clickme"
    android:text="ClickMe" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_list_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parentt" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clickme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_above="@id/clickme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You have a `Button` at the bottom and a `ViewGroup` which is a `FrameLayou`t at the top. You add the `Fragment` to the container.

And in ManiActivtiy change to

```
  ft.add(R.id.container, fragment, TAG_LIST);
```